# Values of SObject map are lost after a DML call

Tags: apex, map, sobject, dml

Can anyone explain the comments in this snippet?

```
Map<Account, Contact> m = new Map<Account, Contact>();
m.put(new Account(Name='Test'), new Contact(Lastname='Test'));

SObject[] records = new SObject[]{};
for (Account acc : m.keySet()) records.add(acc);
insert records;

System.debug(m); // returns {Account:{Name=Test, Id=0013600001BkcJYABC}=null}

System.debug(m.values()); // returns (Contact:{LastName=Test})
```

Specifically the map seems to lose its values once its keys are DML'd upon, and yet, the values appear to be there!

I think it is obvious that the map cannot identify its keys once they receive Ids. This looks like a pass-by-reference bug to me.

Answer (score 15):

Using complex objects as Map keys can have unexpected consequences.

In your example, the insert causes the Id of the key Account to be updated so the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the Account produce different results after that. But the Map was setup with the original `hashCode` and `equals` results. Effectively you have modified the key and that has broken the contract of the Map.

Using an [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) value as the key - such as an Id or a String or an Integer - is much safer.

Comment: Great explanation, I didn't know! :)

Comment: Agreed. Ever since apex started allowing objects as members of `Set` and keys of `Map`, I've seen lots of developers try to use them and end up with surprising behavior. I haven't seen any use cases for sObject sets that aren't solved just as easily some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Once you updated Account, key in map is changed (as now Id field and its value differs, from original value). That means, that new hashCode is differs. This is a  new key,  and this map has no value for this key